# How do I use Querystring to grab different information from a database

Tags: asp.net

I have set up query string on lets just say for now a product page:

This is in product.cs:

```
int ProductID = Convert.ToInt32( Request.QueryString["pid"] );
```

product.aspx - Below is the code to set each link, if you click the below link it will take you to a page product and its unique to product 4
Modern Warfare

You click product page it gives you a list with images off products, you click one of the products I want it to go to a unique page for purpose off this lets say individual_product.aspx. I would like this page to work like the above `individual_product.aspx/?pid=4`

If pid = 4 show one lot of information from the database with images, if you hit product 2 the same goes with different information. I just wasnt sure how I would code this up. I guess I make a page, make a loop through each pid, if pid =1 then grab info 1 from database etc etc.

I always know the theory but I am struggling on how to code it.
Any help would be awesome thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like this in a ListView - each link bringing user to the product details page:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <a href="individual_product.aspx?pid=<%# Convert.ToInt(Eval("pid")) %>">
    <img src="Images/<%# Eval("image") %>" /></a>
    <br /> 
    <b><%#Eval("title") %></b>
</ItemTemplate>
```